# Cannot CREATE DATABASE ... EF 4.2 code-first + June 2011 CTP in Unit Tests using SQLExpress and |DataDirectory|

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-express

The query generated by EF is the following:

```
create database [Test] on primary (name=N'Test.mdf', filename=N'\Test.mdf') log on (name=N'Test_log.ldf', filename=N'I:\Test_log.ldf')
```

The connection string:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=Test; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Test.mdf;
```

Dependencies:

- Entity Framework 4.2 Preview (Nuget)
- Entity Framework June 2011 CTP
- A Unit test project (using NUnit)
- SQLExpress
- AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Test.mdf;

In order for all this to work, I had to specify an absolute path for AttachDbFilename.

I've been able to use it on a different set-up but after installing CTP it won't work. Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the database file on the I: drive, the problem could therefore be rights related.

To test if it is a rights issue: Try creating a folder on the local C drive, give Everyone full controll, and then change the connections to use that folder.

Comment: Creating the database on drive I: works. Creating the database with |DataDirectory| doesn't.